# DirectorySearcher - what exception is returned when the users password is about to expire?

Tags: c#, directorysearcher

I have an application uses the following code:

```
    private SearchResult DirectorySearch(string userName, string password, string property)
    {
         DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAPServer"].ToString(), FilterOutDomain(userName.Trim()), password);
         DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);

         search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);
         search.Filter = "sAMAccountName=" FilterOutDomain(userName);

         SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
         return result;
    }
```

And this method call is in a try catch (the catch is for when the user fails to authenticate). However, I have noticed authentication failing when the users password is due to expire (i.e. in 7 days). It's difficult to test this, so does anyone know what exception is exactly returned so I can catch this and still allow logon?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to contrive this situation in a test environment and added a catchall try/catch block to see what is thrown?